# Is there a way of having multiple plots inside a single datapoint for use with a classifier?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, classification

I am trying to make classification predictions using the readings from multiple sensors over a period of time. In theory I would like 8 arrays with about 5 values to be interpreted as a single point of data in a way a classifier will be able to understand.

If this is not possible then I'd be interested to hear any other ideas for how I could do this.

I have tried simply having the values on the same row together however I'm not convinced this will work.

Example of what I have now with 2 plots in a single datapoint:

```
   A1  A2  A3  A4  B1  B2  B3  B4
1   1   2   1   4   3   2   1   0
2   1   2   1   4   3   2   1   0
3   1   2   1   4   3   2   1   0
```

Example of what I would like:

```
               A               B
1   [1, 2, 1, 4]    [3, 2, 1, 0]
2   [1, 2, 1, 4]    [3, 2, 1, 0]
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean like this?

```
import io
import pandas as pd

data = """A1  A2  A3  A4  B1  B2  B3  B4
1   2   1   4   3   2   1   0
1   2   1   4   3   2   1   0
1   2   1   4   3   2   1   0"""

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), delim_whitespace=True)

df["A"] = pd.Series(df[["A1", "A2", "A3", "A4"]].values.tolist())
df["B"] = pd.Series(df[["B1", "B2", "B3", "B4"]].values.tolist())

print(df)
```

Which prints:

```
   A1  A2  A3  A4  B1  B2  B3  B4             A             B
0   1   2   1   4   3   2   1   0  [1, 2, 1, 4]  [3, 2, 1, 0]
1   1   2   1   4   3   2   1   0  [1, 2, 1, 4]  [3, 2, 1, 0]
2   1   2   1   4   3   2   1   0  [1, 2, 1, 4]  [3, 2, 1, 0]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This looks like the format I am trying to achieve however I am uncertain if a classifier (that isn't specifically written for this) will be capable of understanding the data the way I want it to. I'll have a play with this compared to sending it all the data unformatted and see if it accepts it and if it performs differently.